# No Beeping with NSBeep()

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, appkit

I have never used `NSBeep`.  I've imported `AppKit.framework` to the project.  Under Xcode 8.2 with Swift 3, I have

```
import AppKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSBeep() 
    }
}
```

And there's no beeping.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you turn on the volume?

Comment: @GeneCode Yes, I have.

Answer (score 8):

For **Xcode 9.0+**, try using `NSSound.beep()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Change `applicationWillFinishLaunching` to `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Even better (since some of the other stuff you said is rather weird), start with the built-in template for a Cocoa macOS application and put `NSBeep()` into the existing `applicationDidFinishLaunching` implementation. I did that and built-and-ran, and I heard the beep.